# react-router: need a easy way to fetch current component and name serverside

Tags: react-router

current the only way I can fetch the current component and its name from the current route is as following.

```
match({routes, location: request.url.path }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    var componentName = renderProps.components[1].displayName.replace(/Connect\(|\)/g, '');
    var componentObj = renderProps.components[1].WrappedComponent;
});
```

is there a simpler way I can do this in a simpler way?

my main reason to do this is to prefetch data for rendering serverside, its works fairly well as above but looks quite hacky.

Comment: using version v1.0.0